# What would be the best approach to A/B test guest/sign-in checkout?

Tags: conversion, ab-experiment

It would be wonderful to be able to get some concrete statistics to prove that providing a guest checkout feature can really help increase conversion.

Does anybody have a good method for A/B testing in Magento that will allow for presenting:

- Checkout requiring sign in to pay (to A)
- Checkout with ability to pay as guest, with option to sign in (to B)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use your A/B tool to hide the radio button for Guest Checkout:

- Your control (A) group will be Guest Checkout Showing
- Your test (B) group will be registered-only, with Guest Checkout being hidden via Javascript.

Because most a/b testing tools require Javascript (GWO, Optimizely, etc.) you'll be using the following Javascript to effectively remove the radio button from the page (e.g. here in plain old javascript). In essence, all that your test is adding to the page is **this javascript snippet**:

```
<script>
/* Remove Control <li> Where Radio Button Guest Exists */
document.getElementById('login:guest').parentNode.remove(this);
<script>
```

You may also consider changing some of the text via Javascript's innerHtml to remove any references to guest checkout if that is going to be part of the checkout page design.

**Edit:**

As a side-note many tools such as Optimizely have visual editors to help you perform these types of tests live, on-page, no code required.

Answer (score -1):

I can help you with a quick outcome of this particular A/B test.... allowing customers to checkout as guests will give higher conversion rates. It has already been tested and proven by many stores that requiring to register is experienced by many potiential customers as a burden and results in less conversions.

Comment: Wholeheartedly agree and am aware of the proof, however, unfortunately sometimes the people that make decisions want to see evidence in their own environment before taking a leap.