# How to A/B test two different onepage extensions on magento?

Tags: onepage-checkout, testing

I'm successfully able to A/B test product pages/CMS pages. However, I'm having difficulty testing two different onepage extensions.

I want 50% of users to use one onepage extension and the other 50% to use another onepage extension.

How would I go about A/B testing two different onepage extensions? Is there a service which supports this type of test or would I need a custom build and require google analytics for results?

Answer (score 1):

- Here is some info about track guest / sign in checkout [What would be the best approach to A/B test guest/sign-in checkout?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1035/what-would-be-the-best-approach-to-a-b-test-guest-sign-in-checkout)
- A / B Testing Magento Checkout by Optimizely - https://community.optimizely.com/t5/Using-Optimizely/Best-practices-for-testing-different-full-checkout-flows-in/m-p/9214#M2390
- Different extensions and services for Magento A/B Testing https://firebearstudio.com/blog/ab-testing-for-magento.html

Answer (score 0):

the most easy way to do that is, enable 1 checkout at time and measure everiting with kissmetrics or create a pad in analytics,

Answer (score 0):

You can set two server instances with your two versions. Place a load balancer infront of them and check which one performs better.